# MVVM Binding buttons in ListView item within a ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, template10

In a UWP-Windows 10 C#/XAML app using MVVM and Template10, I'm currently trying to bind buttons inside a ListView item to methods in the ViewModel in the following way:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ViewModel" x:Key="TermListViewTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="termListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind childModels, Mode=OneWay}"
                      ItemClick="EntityListClick">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="gl:Term">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button Click="EditButton_Click">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit"></SymbolIcon>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Click="DeleteButton_Click">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete"></SymbolIcon>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Where `EntityListClick`, `EditButton_Click`, and `DeleteButton_Click` are all methods in the codebehind file, that then call a method in the `ViewModel` as so:

```
private void EntityListClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.termClick((Term)e.ClickedItem);
}

private void EditButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.editTerm((Term)(sender as Button).DataContext);
}

private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.deleteTerm((Term)(sender as Button).DataContext);
}
```

How would I correctly implement the MVVM patterns in this scenario to directly bind to `ViewModel.termClick`, `ViewModel.editTerm`, and `ViewModel.deleteTerm`, in the `ViewModel` while passing the correct parameter to the `ViewModel`?

Additionally I have a button in the XAML whose `Click` event handler is attached to the following method in the code behind:

```
private async void AddTerm_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ViewModel.addTermAsync();
    ListView termListView = (ListView)((Grid)((Button)sender).Parent).Children[2];
    termListView.ScrollIntoView(termListView.Items[termListView.Items.Count - 1]);
}
```

Once again, is there some way to properly link the click handler to the ViewModel directly, in such a way that the ListView can be scrolled? (perhaps some way of binding the ListView's entire instance to a property of type "ListView" in the ViewModel?)

Comment: Instead of attaching a Click handler, bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand property in the view model.

Comment: What's your min target version of Windows 10?

Comment: @JustinXL Currently 10586 (November Update), but could be changed. Why?

Comment: @Clemens Wouldn't that bring up the issue of not being able to bind straight to ViewModel properties from inside an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate of type `Term`? Also, how will the ViewModel know which Button (and which associated ListView item/Term object) is sending the command?

Comment: You can use `x:Bind` to bind to an event starting from 14393.

Comment: @JustinXl I've tried that but am not able to bind straight to ViewModel properties from inside an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate of type `Term`. Also how does the ViewModel know which ListView item/Term object fired the event?

Comment: Actually just had a look at your code again, although *`x:Bind` to event* may work, it will introduce unnecessary complexity when used inside a data template since you will have to define these event handlers in your model class `Term`. As @Clemens already suggested, you can use `Command` and inside your data template, simply do `<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.editTermCommand, ElementName=termListView}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />`. This way you can have all your `Command`s living inside your top level VM. The `CommandParameter` will also give you exactly which `Term` it is.

Comment: @cloudcrypt You might as well have the commands in the Term class. Binding would be as simple as `Command="{Binding Edit}"`, assuming there is a `public ICommand Edit { get; set; }` in class Term. As a note, you don't have to specify the DataType of the DataTemplate that is assigned to ListView.ItemTemplate. DataType is meant to support automatic template seclection, which doesn't happen here.